# Executerservice submits task invokes code after time out

Tags: executorservice

I have below code, the doTransaction method is getting invoked after 20 seconds, could any one tell me why its taking that long to invoke doTransaction method.
Its not happening always its happening very rarely. Any help on this is appreciated.
Thanks,

```
        ExecutorService service =  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();          

    TransactionTask task = new TransactionTask(object);
    Future<Result> future = service.submit(task);
    Result r = future.get(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);


    class TransactionTask implements Callable<Result> {
        private Request req = null;
            public TransactionTask(Request trx){
            this.req = trx;
        }
    @Override
    public Result call() throws Exception  {
        Result o = doTransaction(req);  

        return o;

    }
    }
```

Comment: How often are you submitting the task? Only once or multiple time?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Task is submitted only once and one task at a time, the code is on Tomcat server, above code will be invoke once per request. T

Comment: Tomcat handles each request concurrently, are you creating ExecutorService for every request. If no, then that's it, multiple tasks are created and submitted by tomcat in same service.

Comment: I am creating ExecutorService for every request

Answer (score 0):

The above behavior could be explained if you submit multiple tasks.

The `ExecutorService` you created is single threaded, so it could only execute only one task concurrently. Other tasks if submitted will be in queue and will start executing if the former task is `terminated/completed`

It executes only after 20 seconds because in `future.get(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` you cancel the already running task. Could you check that you are not getting `CancellationException`.

**Edit:**
Since you are using Tomcat which is concurrent in execution, I would suggest, you use multithread instead of single thread if not necessary:- `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N);` for having N tasks executing concurrently and increase the timout